# Need reference for $\phi(Z)=Z'$ if and only if $\Phi: \operatorname{Prim}(Z')\to \operatorname{Prim}(Z)$ is injective

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras with centers $Z$ and $Z'$ respectively. Let $\phi:A \to B$ be surjective $C^{\ast}$-morphism. Then

> $\phi(Z)=Z'$ if and only if the map $\Phi: \operatorname{Prim}(Z') \to \operatorname{Prim}(Z)$ defined as $\Phi(J) = \phi^{-1}(J)$ is injective.

Can someone please give me reference for the above result?

The above result is mentioned without proof in Proposition $1$ of the paper titled [On the homomorphic image of Center of $C^{\ast}$-algebras](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-11040) by Vesterstrom.

P.S: The same was asked on mathoverflow too but unfortunately dint get any answer. Copy of the same question on mathoverflow can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366661/need-reference-for-phiz-z-if-and-only-if-phi-operatornameprimz-to).

Comment: This is because $Z \cong C(\text{Prim}(Z))$, so what you ask follows from the fact that a map $f:X\to Y$ is surjective iff the induced map $f^{\ast} : C(Y) \to C(X)$ is injective.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan:  Isn't it primitive ideal maximal modular instaed of just maximal?